# Construction of real numbers using Cauchy sequences argument

Tags: real-analysis

This segment was taken from wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Construction_of_the_real_numbers#Construction_from_Cauchy_sequences

Claim: A non-empty bounded subset $S\subset \mathbb{R}$ has a least upper bound.

Wikipedia Proof:
Let $U$ be an upper bound of $S$. WLOG, let $U$ be rational, since every Cauchy rational sequence representing a real number can be upper bounded by a particular rational number. Since $S$ non-empty, choose rational number $L$ such that $L<s$ for some $s\in S$.

Then define the sequences $(u_n), (l_n)$.
Set $u_0 = U$ and $l_0 = L$.

For each n consider the number:

$m_n = (u_n + l_n)/2$

If $m_n$ is an upper bound for $S$ set:

$u_{n+1} = m_n$ and $l_{n+1} = l_n$

Otherwise set:

$l_{n+1} = m_n$ and $u_{n+1} = u_n$

This defines two Cauchy sequences of rationals, and so we have real numbers $l = (l_n)$ and $u = (u_n)$. It is easy to prove, by induction on $n$ that:

$u_n$ is an upper bound for $S$ for all $n$ and

$l_n$ is never an upper bound for $S$ for any $n$

Thus $u$ is an upper bound for $S$. To see that it is a least upper bound, notice that the limit of $(u_n − l_n)$ is 0, and so $l = u$. Now suppose $b < u = l$ is a smaller upper bound for $S$. Since $(l_n)$ is monotonic increasing **it is easy to see that (why?)** $b < l_n$ for some $n$. But $l_n$ is not an upper bound for $S$ and so neither is $b$. Hence $u$ is a least upper bound for $S$.

I do not understand the claim that $(l_n)$ monotonically increasing implies $b < l_n$ for some $n$. The way I see it, to show that $\exists N\in \mathbb{N}, n\geq N\implies b < l_n$, it suffices to consider the fact that $l=(l_n)$ regardless of monotonicity of $(l_n)$, and the Cauchy nature of $(b_n)$.

My argument goes:

First, to give a definition of strict order on Cauchy sequences, $(a_n)<_{\mathbb{R}}(b_n)$ iff there exists $\epsilon \in \mathbb{Q}, \epsilon > 0$ such that $a_n + \epsilon < b_n$ for all but finitely many $n$. I believe this definition, coupled with the definition of equivalence of Cauchy sequences, is logically equivalent to the definition of the non-strict order $\geq_{\mathbb{R}}$ we see on Wikipedia.

$\exists \epsilon \in \mathbb{Q}_{>0}, N_1\in \mathbb{N}, s.t. n\geq N_1\implies b_n +\epsilon <_{\mathbb{Q}} l_n$. (By definition of strict order $<_\mathbb{R}$)

$\exists N_2\in \mathbb{N}, s.t. m,n\geq N_2\implies |b_m-b_n|_\mathbb{Q} < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. (By Cauchy property of $(b_n)$)

Let $N=max(N_1,N_2)$. This is so that both desired properties above will hold for $n\geq N$.
Then $n\geq N\implies b_n<b_N+\frac{\epsilon}{2}<b_N+\epsilon<l_N$, which says that $b=(b_1, b_2, \dots) <_{\mathbb{R}} (I_N, I_N, \dots) = l_N$.

Comment: I suggest using less symbols and more complete English sentences if you want a quicker answer.

Comment: Is my question clear enough now? I can't really think of a nicer way to express the last part in English.

Comment: In particular, it couldn't hurt to include the definitions of the sequences $u_n$ and $I_n$, which the question seems to be about. The community overwhelmingly prefers fairly self-contained questions that can be posed without clicking into another place. (People do commonly include links to references or supplementary material, however, and I appreciate this helpful practice. But for some people, it's too much to leave out main ingredients in the question. They won't bother to look even if they might have otherwise offered guidance.)